# AutoDesk API for List of Fusion 360 Files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-data-management

Using the Autodesk Forge Auth API, I can get a bearer token for my app and I can get the ID of the user. I want to get a list of Fusion 360 files that the user owns. How can I do this? It seems like it would be part of the Data Management API, but I can't find it.

I use the forge api for data management to ask for the hubs for a user. I get a response that has a 200 status, but there is nothing in the response - no data and nothing like what is in the [example](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/hubs-GET/).

Any ideals as to how to get those files?

Answer (score 0):

If the GET Hubs response is empty, most likely that user don't have any hub. Is there any warning or error on the response body?

And [this tutorial](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels) should help you get started, or try [this live sample](https://forgedatamanagement.herokuapp.com) (source in [.NET](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-csharp-sample))

Comment: There is no error or warning. The status code was 200. It was for my account and I obviously have Fusion 360 files. If this is not the proper method to access those files, what is the proper method?

Comment: I really don't understand that tutorial. There doesn't seem to be any code or explanation. There is just a gif with some links that do not explain anything at all. The sample is also broken.

Comment: @JoshuaFoxworth sorry the delay. Sorry about these problems. The GET Hubs should return your hubs, have you tried the live version? Nothing there? About the tutorial, I just tested all links there, all working... the link I gave you is just the first, you have to follow the steps.

Comment: So, I have been able to get a hub ID through a direct curl. There are still times when only an error code is returned and I am looking into why that is. I am not sure why this was happening. I removed all of the APIs that the app was allowed to access and then reassigned them and that seemed to help.